# Show that $ζ$ is a Quadratic Integer in $Q[\sqrt{−3}]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-integer-rings

So in the complex plane, there are three cube roots of one. Suppose we let $ζ$ be the cube root of one which has positive imaginary part. How can we show that $ζ$ is a quadratic integer in $Q[\sqrt{−3}]$ by writing it in the form $(a+b\sqrt{−3})/2$, where $a$ and $b$ are rational integers and $a$ and $b$ are either both even or both odd. Additionally what steps would I take to also write it in the form $$m + n(\frac{1 + \sqrt{−3}}{2})$$, where $m$ and $n$ are rational integers.

Comment: have you tried simply computing $(\frac{a+b\sqrt{-2}}2)^3$?

Comment: You can compute $\zeta$. We know that $\zeta^3-1=0$. Therefore $(\zeta-1)(\zeta^2+\zeta+1)=0$. Since $\zeta\neq1$ we know it is a root of $\zeta^2+\zeta+1=0$. We get $\zeta=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. This you can write also as $-1+1\cdot\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ohhh. I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(x)=x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

and since $\;\zeta\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R\;$ and it is a root of $\;p(x)\;$ , it *must* be a root of the above quadratic.

We also have that

$$\zeta=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i=-1+\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$$